# Schedule job after 12 hours with application is running in background.

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I am trying to schedule a job service when i receive BOOT_COMPLETED. Job is getting scheduled immediately and again getting scheduled periodically.
Here depending on some local criteria some time i need to delay the scheduling of job so i can call scheduleJob of scheduler after this delay.

My app does not have any UI and always runs in background , to provide delay i tried timer task , handler etc but these only worked in foreground conditions.
As my app is running in background these did not helped me .

I again tried starting intent service as foreground service and in onHandleIntent trying to sleep the thread for specified time.Once sleep time is over i am scheduling the job and stopForgroundService . Max delay i need to handle is 24 hours.

Is this correct approach to provide delay of max 24 hours and hold it using foreground service or is there any other way i can achieve this.

IntentService, TimerTask

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent . I think (might be wrong) it's achievable with BroadcastReceiver, just a regular service to do the job, and PendingIntent.

Comment: Krzysztof Kubicki Thanks for suggestions ,let me try this also.

Comment: background work is limited after Android Api 26 refer to this link https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background, if you are interested to run service, your service should have notification.

Comment: I am using intent service as foreground service by posting notification which will hold and provide me the required delay in onhandleIntent as below- 

private void startTimerTask() {

       try {
            Log.d(TAG,"Putting schedule delay for time (in milliseconds) = "+ mTaskDelay);
            //TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(mTaskDelay);
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(2*60*1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
           Utils.scheduleJob(TimerTaskService.this);
       }
    }

Comment: I'm shooting blindly here, but have you tried starting the ForegroundService in seperate process?

Comment: Foreground service is in same process . In onHandleIntent i am calling startTimerTask and posting notification to hold. After sleep interrupted , job is scheduled and stopForeground is called. Here worries are max delay can be 24 hour.

Comment: Is there any comment on sleeping my intent service for 24 hours and "TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(24*60*60*1000); " . 24 hours are maximum time.